# How to make SearchBar in tableview work?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

So i am trying to make an application that displays names of people in a tableview and on tap moves to the next view controller that shows an image of the person.
However when i add the search bar on the table view; i dont seem to have it right.

What am i doing wrong here?
The code compiles and displays on the simulator but when i click on any of the buttons, it gives me the errors i hate the most (Thread 1 : signal SIGABRT)

Here is my code for the Table View Controller

```
#import "PhotoTableViewController.h"
#import "Photo.h"
#import "DisplayViewController.h"

@interface PhotoTableViewController ()

@end

@implementation PhotoTableViewController
@synthesize photoSearchBar, showPhotos, filteredPhotos;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    showPhotos = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                           [Photo photoofname:@"Main" filename:@"photo1.jpg" notes:@"Amazing Road Bike"],
                           [Photo photoofname:@"Back" filename:@"photo3.jpg" notes:@"this is the back"], nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    self.filteredPhotos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[showPhotos count]];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [filteredPhotos count];
    } else {
        return [showPhotos count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"PCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    Photo *photo = nil;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        photo = [filteredPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }else
    {
        photo = [showPhotos objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = photo.name;
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark Content Filtering

-(void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope {
    // Update the filtered array based on the search text and scope.
    // Remove all objects from the filtered search array
    [self.filteredPhotos removeAllObjects];
    // Filter the array using NSPredicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.name contains[c] %@",searchText];
    filteredPhotos = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[showPhotos filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
}

#pragma mark - UISearchDisplayController Delegate Methods
-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when text changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption {
    // Tells the table data source to reload when scope bar selection changes
    [self filterContentForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - TableView Delegate
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Perform segue to candy detail
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"candyDetail" sender:tableView];
}

#pragma mark - Segue
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"photoDetail"]) {
        UIViewController *candyDetailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        // In order to manipulate the destination view controller, another check on which table (search or normal) is displayed is needed
        if(sender == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[filteredPhotos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }
        else {
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
            NSString *destinationTitle = [[showPhotos objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] name];
            [candyDetailViewController setTitle:destinationTitle];
        }

    }
}
```

Also this is the code for my Objective C Class called Photo

```
#import "Photo.h"

@implementation Photo

@synthesize name,filename,notes;

+(id) photoofname: (NSString*)name filename:(NSString*)filename notes:(NSString*)notes{
    Photo *newPhoto = [[Photo alloc]init];
    newPhoto.name = name;
    newPhoto.filename = filename;
    newPhoto.notes = notes;
    return newPhoto;
}

@end
```

Comment: can you post the exception log?

Comment: Can you please post the log messages ?

Comment: @JohnWoods
Thank you for your inputs; turns out it was a small error on myside while naming the reuse identifier of the segue.

Eventhough now the transition of tableview to imageview is working; the images are not showing up on the image view.

Currently i have no errors during compilation and works fine; just that the images are not loading/showing up.

Could you please review the code with this aspect in mind ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, just by looking at the code what I can suggest you is, first remove that call to prepareForSegue method called in UITableView's delegate method, didSelectForRowAtIndexPath.
You are overriding prepareForSegue, so in your storyboard you should have a prototype cell from where you have to ctrl-drag to the destination controller and segue it accordingly. That's a basic concept. Still having problem? Let us see your console messages when it crashes.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs; turns out it was a small error on myside while naming the reuse identifier of the segue. 

Eventhough now the transition of tableview to imageview is working; the images are not showing up on the image view. Currently i have no errors during compilation and works fine; just that the images are not loading/showing up. Could you please review the code with this aspect in mind ?

Comment: Well, your code tells me that you have all your images in filteredPhotos encapsulated in a Photo object. But where is the line of code where you are setting that image to an instance of image view? As in, If you have an UIImageView object, then you are supposed to use setImage method on that object with an instance of UIImage.

Comment: Woohoo !
Thanks a lot. Just got it to work.

Can you also help with this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18074366/how-to-generate-custom-table-view-based-on-textfield-input

Comment: If the answer with the comments have helped you in solving your problem, then please accept this as an answer.