# How to generate custom table view based on textfield input?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar

I am trying to create an app which has a simple root view controller with a textfield and a button.
I want to create a custom table view based on the input of the user in the text field.

Imagine this :  An App that shows you a list of bikes based on the search input in the text field.
Say the user inputs : "Blue Bike" in the text field, the next view will be the one with a table view controller showing all the cells that have Blue or Bike as words in the title.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through this !? [UISearchDisplayController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchDisplayController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Yes, but can i implement the search functionality with having the search bar on a different view controller; in this case the root view controller ?

Comment: You can but that breaks the application flow since the same data has been passed on to another view. The data you get after searching should be obviously the subset of the original data so its better you reload the same tableview with the new fetched search result and when the user clears the textfield reload the data again with the entire original datasource.

Comment: Well, either i am not able to explain what i am trying to achieve or i am unable to understand exactly what you recommend.

I have a textfield (like google's home page) and based on the text input in that field, a custom table view shows up (Search results of Google but in table view)

So should i add a search bar to the root view controller or a textfield ?
You see the table view and the textfield / searchbar are not in the same view controller.

P.S : iOS Beginner. Apologies for naive questions.